# How to access the constant defined inside parameter_types! () macro

Tags: pallet-treasury

While configuring any pallet (treasury pallet in my case), we need to configure some required associative types. To set the values of these required types, we mostly define some constants within the `parameter_types!()` macro.

I will quote here the example of pallet_treasury configuration in Kusama [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L611).

In the given example, a constant is defined to be used for `PalletId` required associative type like this:

```rs
pub const TreasuryPalletId: PalletId = PalletId(*b"py/trsry");
```

Now my question is, can we refer to that constant anywhere else in our runtime code? if Yes how?

Answer (score 2):

`parameter_types` will implement the `Get` for you.

Just:

```rs
fn example() {
    let treasury_pallet_id = TreasuryPalletId::get();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have the config of the pallet like `impl pallet_treasury::Config for Runtime` and before it you define the constants of that pallet with the `parameter_types!` macro but is not mandatory to have one  `parameter_types!` defined before each pallet is just for readability, you can have one at the top of your code file with the constants of all pallets.

See this example in the Kusama runtime:
The const [MaximumReasonLength](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L671) is defined once and used in the [pallet_bounties](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L671) and in the [pallet_tips](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L688).

Another option is define it like a const, in the Kusama runtime take a look into the const `VERSION` defined [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L124) and used in the pallet [frame_system](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L124) and in the apis implementation [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/master/runtime/kusama/src/lib.rs#L1584).